# passing conditions to helm dependencies

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I created a helm chart and i have some dependencies in chart.yaml .
One of them is cert-manager and I need the chart to be deployed in 'cert-manager' namespace.
I have a yaml file which creates the namespace and the other resources controlled by cert manager are configured to use that namespace.
However, when i run 'helm install' the namespace is created but the resources are not in that namespace, and it gives me the next error:

`Error: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": service "cert-manager-webhook" not found`

I read that it is caused because cert manager has a problem with its namespace configuration and can't be deployed in any other one if its installed via dependency.

Comment: share the helm yaml template for more details .

Comment: you can change the namespace `helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace new-namespace \
  --create-namespace \
  --version v1.6.0`

Comment: Helm will deploy the whole Release in one namespace. So all charts will be automatically installed in the namespace you set with _--namespace_ on `helm install`. Do not set the namespace directly inside the yaml files.